# The transition between 2 pages works, but the same CSS is always used for both pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I was experimenting with the main swup.js animation, but there's a problem. The effect works, but the same css file is always loaded for 2 or more different pages even if on the second page I indicate a different css file.

I leave you the snippet to make you understand. If you know how to avoid this behavior please let me know.

This is the snippet of page1. copy and paste the code into your editor and obviously you have to include the css file in the head. You will need to do the same for page2 as well.

```css
.transition-fade {
    transition: 0.4s;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  html.is-animating .transition-fade {
    opacity: 0;
  }



  h1
  {
    color: rgb(86, 139, 0);
    font: 2rem;
  }
```

```html
<main id="swup" class="transition-fade">
   <h1>This is page1</h1>
   <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
      labore et dolore magna aliqua.
   </p>
   <a href="/page1.html">page1</a>
   <a href="/page2.html">page2</a>
</main>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/swup@latest/dist/swup.min.js"></script>
    
<script>
   const swup = new Swup();
</script>
```

the snippet of page2:

```css
.transition-fade {
  transition: 0.4s;
  opacity: 1;
}

html.is-animating .transition-fade {
  opacity: 0;
}



h1
{
  color: darkmagenta;
}
```

```html
 <main id="swup" class="transition-fade">
   <h1>This is page2</h1>
   <p>
       ciao questa e' la pagina 2
   </p>
   <a href="/proviamo-swup/page1.html">pag1</a>
   <a href="/proviamo-swup/page2.html">page2</a>
</main>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/swup@latest/dist/swup.min.js"></script>
<script>
   const swup = new Swup();
</script>
```

You will see that the page effect works, but the page1.css file is always applied as css. I would like each page to have its own css.

Comment: Look into the [Head Plugin](https://swup.js.org/plugins/head-plugin) of Swup.

Comment: I'd make you a statue of gold ahaha. Thanks, I try to solve, I was going crazy.